# Magento MInimum Order Quantity per customer group

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0

I can see how you can set a Minimum Order Quantity (MOQ) per customer group globally via Config >> Inventory and set in product stock options by adding a minimum quantity by group. But, this would use the same MOQ for all products where I may need MOQ as one on 50% of the store but 25% of the products I need MOQ of 6 and then MOQ on another 25% of 3.

Is there a way of doing this? I have searched for answers and extensions but nothing seems to do this. I need it per group as all products for retail sales would have MOQ of 1 for all products so I cannot set in each product what the MOQ would be as I have done in the Trade website in the past. We now want it to be trade and retail. I am sure someone has made an extension for this so if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you could set the "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" on each product individually - is that not what you mean?

Comment: that is what I want but you can't set MOQ for customer group retail as one then as Customer Group Trade Three for product A but on Product B Retail will still be MOQ one but Trade MOQ would be six.